# With the same ID "566" already exists

Tags: magento2

Item (Magento\Cms\Model\Page) with the same ID "566" already exists.

when i create cms page this error coming

Comment: Record already exists with id 566. Please check in database.

Comment: yes i detete but the issue is when i go to add new page this error come agian

Comment: clear cache and check it.

Comment: Did you got an error while deleting the page? Does the page exist in the database but not in the grid? Did you edit the database and broke auto increment? Please provide more information because this is not a reproducible error.